# where is tcp_delack_min linux tcp kernel parameter?

Tags: linux, tcp, parameters, kernel

I use 2.6.9-89.ELsmp #1 SMP Mon Jun 22 12:31:33 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I want to control tcp delay ack time.
but, i can't find tcp_delack_min parameter.

```
    sysctl -a | grep tcp
    sunrpc.tcp_slot_table_entries = 16
    net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_workaround_signed_windows = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_bic_beta = 819
    net.ipv4.tcp_tso_win_divisor = 8
    net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_bic_low_window = 14
    net.ipv4.tcp_bic_fast_convergence = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_bic = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_vegas_gamma = 2
    net.ipv4.tcp_vegas_beta = 6
    net.ipv4.tcp_vegas_alpha = 2
    net.ipv4.tcp_vegas_cong_avoid = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_westwood = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_low_latency = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_frto = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_adv_win_scale = 2
    net.ipv4.tcp_app_win = 31
    net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096    87380   174760
    net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096    16384   131072
    net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 786432   1048576 1572864
    net.ipv4.tcp_dsack = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_ecn = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_reordering = 3
    net.ipv4.tcp_fack = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 10000
    net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_stdurg = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_abort_on_overflow = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 0
    net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60
    net.ipv4.tcp_retries2 = 15
    net.ipv4.tcp_retries1 = 3
    net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
    net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
    net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
    net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 180000
    net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 262144
    net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 5
    net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 5
    net.ipv4.tcp_retrans_collapse = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
    net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
```

where is tcp_delack_min ???

Answer (score 2):

In the kernel source code:

> ./include/net/tcp.h:#define TCP_DELACK_MAX      ((unsigned)(HZ/5))
>   /* maximal time to delay before sending an ACK */
>
> ./include/net/tcp.h:#define TCP_DELACK_MIN      ((unsigned)(HZ/25))
>   /* minimal time to delay before sending an ACK */

Answer (score 2):

It is only available in certain - mostly realtime focused - kernel branches.  A lot of the documentation relating to this kernel parameter is referring to the MRG (Messaging Realtime-Grid) kernel variant that some RHEL machines will use.